# import of library works in javascript file but fails in typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am very new to Javascript and i have a need to modify legacy code.
I am trying to import a new module @microsoft/applicationinsights-web into my file test.ts .
Unfortunately it says module not found even though the module is present in node_modules.

As soon as I rename the file to test.js , it starts working.
Please find my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "allowJs": true
  }

}
```

Any help here ?

Answer (score 0):

Your tsconfig seems not very well configured.
Copy this configuration and it should works, note that your build will be in a dist folder, and you will have to run from there the application or use ts-node.

```
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./dist",
"module": "commonjs", // classic format that Node.js understands
"esModuleInterop": true,
"lib": ["es6", "dom"], // use JavaScript API ES6
"target": "es6", // compile to ES6
"allowJs": true, // allow import of JS modules
"types": ["node"]
}
```

It miss for example the node type.

Comment: Thank you Chalom.E , the module is getting detected  in the IDE . However the issue still exists when I am doing a build . Can you please help here

Comment: How the dependency has been installed ? Perhaps it is a node.JS or Typescript version issue ?
How do you import the module in your application ?